# Zero volatility stocks in intraday trading in India

Tags: stocks, india, volatility

I am an intraday trader in India. Out of 150 stocks which are permitted for intraday trading on NSE or BSE I would like to know of a way to find out which stocks have close to zero volatility.

My strategy uses a 1% stop loss and requires assets or equities that don't fluctuate in price too much (whether the stock is moving up or down).

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't looking this up yourself?

Comment: if you have to ask, you shouldn't call yourself an intraday trader. nothing about your paper trading strategy is going to work out in real market conditions with real orders being placed.

Comment: Product/service recommendations are off-topic. That includes specific stock recommendations.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea did you notice that the real and compliant question is "how do I screen for low volatility stocks" ? because the "edit" button is right next to the "close" button

Comment: @CQM You were here, too. So where's your edit? LOL

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I find the rift of consensus from active users alarming here, I actually wanted to know why you didn't see that solution which I considered obvious, since you might actually have a good reason that I didn't consider

Comment: @CQM **1.** Because it leads to another product-recommendation question *("Which screener can do what I need?")*, and, **2.** Because I'd prefer new users to read the site guidelines and edit their own questions, and **3.** Because I already have my *Copy Editor* gold badge and would like to see others edit posts more often, and join the [club](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/badges/33/copy-editor).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea but the answer of screener at all would actually help somebody and lead to an improved repository of information..... like, the goal of this site and the entire stack exchange platform? All three of your reasons are not reasons to vote to close this question. That should concern the rest of us

Comment: @CQM Close votes are retractable, and once a question is fixed that's exactly what I do.

Answer (score 1):

Find a stock screener that has data for the BSE and NSE. You may be able to look directly at volatility but a good stock screener will have the technical analysis indicator called "average true range", ATR for short. This will let you see the average range of price moves over several days.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use easy programming language to imply onto a scan

where you enter Scan all stocks 
display if volume < (less than) 100

Comment: This is incorrect. Just because a stock has little volume does not make it non volatile.. it just makes it illiquid.